# Invoice class: how to change currency

Tags: symbols, invoice

I just wondering if anyone familiar with the invoice class could show me how to change the currency from dollars into pounds. Below is the code needed-I wish to change the dollars in the table into pounds. Note that I got this file from this [link](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/invoice). The invoice.cls file is needed to compile this document. I've had a look at this [link](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=25959&sid=a2cbce9b25e7156b7ac14b302bc216af) but it doesn't really explain how to do this in other currencies.

```
\documentclass{invoice}

\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} 

\begin{document}

\hfil{\Huge\bf Initech Inc.}\hfil 
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ 
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bf Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bf Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ 

\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} 

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12} 
\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}{12}
\hourrow{October 5, 2012}{5.25}{12}
\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{9.75}{20}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{5}{12.51}

\feetype{Accounting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{2}{80}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{1}{80}

\feetype{Hosting Expenses} 

\feerow{Web Hosting: October, 2012}{60} 

\end{invoiceTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarlosViegas, thanks for that works like magic. i was initially trying the suggestion in the link provided but wasnt working. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of dollar signs is hard-coded in the template as `\$`. If you want a complete replacement of `$` with `£`, you can add

```
\renewcommand{\$}{\pounds}
```

to your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{invoice}

\def\tab{\hspace*{3ex}} 
\renewcommand{\$}{\pounds}% $ -> £
\begin{document}

\hfil{\Huge\bfseries Initech Inc.}\hfil 
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ 
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bfseries Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bfseries Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ 

\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} 

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12} 
\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}{12}
\hourrow{October 5, 2012}{5.25}{12}
\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{9.75}{20}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{5}{12.51}

\feetype{Accounting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{2}{80}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{1}{80}

\feetype{Hosting Expenses} 

\feerow{Web Hosting: October, 2012}{60} 

\end{invoiceTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, even easier than changing individual `\$` symbol.

Comment: @John Yes, it is. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit `invoice.cls` and look for `\$` and change it for whatever you want. Probably change to `\pounds`. Take a look at lines 62, 69, 74, 80 and 107.

Comment: Better yet, the explicit `\$` should become something like `\invoice@currency`, with the addition `\newcommand{\setinvoicecurrency}[1]{\def\invoice@currency{#1}}` and `\setinvoicecurrency{\$}` to end the class, so users can add `\setinvoicecurrency{\pounds}` (or whatever symbol) in their documents, to change the default.